# single-row subquery returns more than one row using subqueries

Tags: sql

I need some assistance with my query.  Below is a sample of my query.  It appears by process of elimination the issue is around CAL.ACTION based on commenting out lines and using AND ROWNUM<=1.  Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    CON.CUSTOMERID||'-'||CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER CONTRACT_NAME,  
    CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
    (
        SELECT 
        B.VALUEDATE
        FROM BTV B, VARIABLES V
        WHERE B.VARIABLE_ID = V.VARIABLE_ID
            AND V.NAME = 'ExecutionDate'
            AND B.CONTRACTID = CON.ID
            AND B.REVISION = CON.REVISION
    ) EXECUTION_DATE,
    CON.STATUS CONTRACT_STATUS,
    (
        SELECT 
            IND.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || IND.LAST_NAME
            FROM INDIVIDUAL IND, CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
            WHERE IND.PARTY_ID = CAL.ORIGINATOR_ID
                AND CAL.ACTION = 'Request Review Task'
                AND CAL.CONTRACT_ID = CON.ID
    ) REVIEW_REQUEST_BY,
    (
        SELECT 
            CC.COMMENTTEXT
        FROM CONTRACTCOMMENT CC, CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
        WHERE CC.CONTRACTID = CAL.CONTRACT_ID
            AND CC.CONTRACT_COMMENT_ID = CAL.COMMENT_ID
            AND CAL.ACTION = 'Finish Review Task'
            AND CC.CONTRACTID = CON.ID
    ) REVIEWER_COMMENT
FROM CONTRACT CON
WHERE CONTRACT_NUMBER = 138006;
```

Comment: there might multiple request review task actions , in that select the first entry

Answer (score 0):

To determine the offending subquery, use `COUNT(*) OVER()` and `PARTITION BY` your join field(s) ie:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CONTRACTID) As Dup_CT
FROM CONTRACTCOMMENT CC
JOIN CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
   ON   CC.CONTRACTID = CAL.CONTRACT_ID
    AND CC.CONTRACT_COMMENT_ID = CAL.COMMENT_ID
    AND CAL.ACTION = 'Finish Review Task'
ORDER BY Dup_CT DESC,CC.CONTRACTID
```

Do the same for each subquery, and if you see any `Dup_CT` values greater than 1 then you found your problem.

Also, this isn't causing your problem, but I suggest moving away from deprecated syntax for joining:

```
SELECT CON.CUSTOMERID||'-'||CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER CONTRACT_NAME
      ,CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER
      ,(SELECT B.VALUEDATE
        FROM BTV B
        JOIN VARIABLES V
          ON    B.VARIABLE_ID = V.VARIABLE_ID
            AND V.NAME = 'ExecutionDate'
        WHERE B.CONTRACTID = CON.ID
          AND B.REVISION = CON.REVISION
        ) EXECUTION_DATE
      ,CON.STATUS CONTRACT_STATUS
      ,(SELECT IND.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || IND.LAST_NAME
        FROM INDIVIDUAL IND
        JOIN CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
          ON     IND.PARTY_ID = CAL.ORIGINATOR_ID
             AND CAL.ACTION = 'Request Review Task'
        WHERE CAL.CONTRACT_ID = CON.ID
        ) REVIEW_REQUEST_BY
      ,(SELECT CC.COMMENTTEXT
        FROM CONTRACTCOMMENT CC
        JOIN CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
          ON    CC.CONTRACTID = CAL.CONTRACT_ID
            AND CC.CONTRACT_COMMENT_ID = CAL.COMMENT_ID
            AND CAL.ACTION = 'Finish Review Task'
        WHERE CC.CONTRACTID = CON.ID
        ) REVIEWER_COMMENT
FROM CONTRACT CON
WHERE CONTRACT_NUMBER = 138006;
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide some more insight.  CAL.ACTION has multiple statuses.  I'm concerned with only 2 'Request Review Task' and 'Finish Review Tast'.  With that said this will use the same conditions except the status being called will be different.  See below another example (The ultimate goal is to be able to see how long (days) it's taking ot complete CAL.ACTION between 'Request Review Task' and 'Finish Review Task':

```
    SELECT CON.CUSTOMERID||'-'||CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER CONTRACT_NAME
          ,CON.CONTRACT_NUMBER
    ,(SELECT CC.CREATEDON
    FROM ECM8_OWN.CONTRACTCOMMENT CC
    JOIN ECM8_OWN.CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
    ON CC.CONTRACTID = CAL.CONTRACT_ID
    AND CC.CONTRACT_COMMENT_ID = CAL.COMMENT_ID
    AND CAL.ACTION = 'Request Review Task'
    WHERE CC.CONTRACT_ID = CON.ID) REVIEW_REQUESTED_DATE
    (SELECT CC.CREATEDON
    FROM CONTRACTCOMMENT CC 
    JOIN CONTRACT_ACTIVITY_LOG CAL
    ON CC.CONTRACT_COMMENT_ID = CAL.COMMENT_ID
    AND CC.CONTRACTID = CAL.CONTRACT_ID
    AND CAL.ACTION = 'Finish Review Task'
    WHERE CC.CONTRACT_ID = CON.ID) REVIEW_COMPLETION_DATE
FROM CONTRACT CON
WHERE CONTRACT_NUMBER = 138006;
```